# Not Able to attach Reference of ActiveX Server Files after certain period of time on particular machine

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, reference, vb6, comobject

I am working on VB dotnet. In our project some of the code is written in **Visual basic 6**, So we used DLLs(Binaries) to use that code in our project(com objects), so we make binaries and giving reference of those binaries in our project.

We have two **ActiveX server file**,One of them is **OCR reader** and its file name is **OCRReader.exe**

Previously we were able to **attach binaries(giving reference to the particular project)**, but when I started debugging code in **Visual Basic studio** I am not able to give reference of those ActiveX server files in my project on my machine (We are able to giving reference of binaries on My colleague's machine who is not yet started debugging on Visual basic studio), it gives the following error -

[image]

I have tried to uninstall VB6(by deleting the folder VB98 inside Microsoft visual studio).
Also deleted all registry related to visual basic 6.
Tried by uninstalling and installing the Visual studio 2017.

**Note - i am unregistering and registering the files properly.**

**I need to give the reference of these ActiveX server file in my project**, How do I do that, I am trying to solve it from past 5 days, will anyone please help me out.

Comment: I used to have a book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4302-0668-2 that explained how to use VB6 DLL's in .NET but sorry I gave it away

Comment: What is "Visual Basic studio" ?  Do you mean Visual Studio?

Comment: What exactly did you do to try and register the EXE that caused the error message shown?